# Can someone help me understand what .index is doing in this code?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have the following code:

```
print(df.drop(df[df['Quantity'] == 0].index).rename(columns={'Weight': 'Weight (oz.)'}))
```

I understand what query is trying to do, but I'm lost at why you need to add the " .index " portion?

What is .index doing in this particular code?

For context here is what the dataframe looks like: 
[image]

I looked at the python documentation for dataframe index:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.index.html

but unfortunately it was too vague for me to make sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

The `DataFrame.index` is the index of each record in your dataframe. It is unique to each row even if two rows have the same data in each column. `DataFrame.drop` takes the `index : single label or list-like` and drops those rows that match the index.

So from the code above,

`df[df['Quantity'] == 0]` gets the rows that has `Quantity == 0`,
`df[df['Quantity'] == 0].index` gets the indexes of all rows that has the predicate,
`df.drop(df[df['Quantity'] == 0].index)` this drops all the indices that returned True for that predicate.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I checked `df.drop()`'s documentation. It says that it drops by index. This code first finds the items that has the quantity 0, but because `drop()` works with indexes , it sends the items back to the dataframe and receive their indexes. That's `index`.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable//reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html